# Commit Git "Supermodule" using post-commit hook of submodule with grunt-git and grunt-githooks

Tags: git, gruntjs, git-submodules, githooks, post-commit-hook

I have a git repo which contains many submodules. When I commit in a submodule, I have a git hook which is supposed to commit in the "supermodule". Unfortunately, the commit in the post-commit hook fails because the "supermodule" can't seem to detect the changes in its submodule.

Is there any other way I can achieve this behavior?

I have all this set up through Grunt using `grunt-githooks` and `grunt-git`.

Below is my gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    githooks: {
      all: {
        options: {
            dest: '../../../.git/modules/server/modules/mymodule/hooks'
        },
        'post-commit': 'updateSuperModule'
      }
    },

    gitcommit: {
        all: {
            options: {
                message: 'Updated Submodule',
                cwd: '../../..',
                verbose: true
            },
            files: {
                src: ['.']
            }
        }
    },

    gitpush: {
        all: {
            options: {
                cwd: '../../..',
                verbose: true
            }
        }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-githooks');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-git');
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a commit of a repo (here a submodule) wants to perform a git operation in another repo (here the parent repo, in '`../../..`'), changing folder isn't enough.

You need to unset `GIT_DIR` first, then perform git commands ([as in this hook](https://github.com/knksmith57/git-hook-examples/blob/master/post-update.grunt-build-with-staging.example)).

If you don't, and status or add operation will be run in the context of the submodule (which has just had a new commit, and has a clean status).